# Using test bench code from Practical Common Lisp

Tags: format, common-lisp

In Practical Common Lisp Ch. 9, Peter Seibel provides a basic unit test bench for comparing expected with actual results of evaluating S-expressions. For example, defining a test as `(deftest plus-test () (check (= (+ 1 2) 3)))` and evaluating (plus-test) will print the result `pass ... (PLUS-TEST): (= (+ 1 2) 3)`. However, a slightly more complex example like `(deftest cdr-test () (check (equal (cdr '(a |a| "a" #\a)) '(|a| "a" #\a)` produces the result `pass ... (CDR-TEST): (equal (cdr '(A a a a)) '(a a a))` rather than `pass ... (CDR-TEST): (equal (cdr '(a |a| "a" #\a)) '(|a| "a" #\a))`. I have not been able to successfully modify his code to print the desired result, and would appreciate some assistance. Here is his code from Ch. 9:

```
(defmacro with-gensyms ((&rest names) &body body)
  `(let ,(loop for n in names collect `(,n (make-symbol ,(string n))))
     ,@body))

(defvar *test-name* nil)

(defmacro deftest (name parameters &body body)
  "Define a test function. Within a test function we can call other
   test functions or use `check' to run individual test cases."
  `(defun ,name ,parameters
    (let ((*test-name* (append *test-name* (list ',name))))
      ,@body)))

(defmacro check (&body forms)
  "Run each expression in `forms' as a test case."
  `(combine-results
    ,@(loop for f in forms collect `(report-result ,f ',f))))

(defmacro combine-results (&body forms)
  "Combine the results (as booleans) of evaluating `forms' in order."
  (with-gensyms (result)
    `(let ((,result t))
      ,@(loop for f in forms collect `(unless ,f (setf ,result nil)))
      ,result)))

(defun report-result (result form)
  "Report the results of a single test case. Called by `check'."
  (format t "~:[FAIL~;pass~] ... ~a: ~a~%" result *test-name* form)
  result)
```

Comment: You need to change the `~a` in the FORMAT to `~s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a question about `format` control, since the function `format` does the output in the code you are using.

The corresponding Common Lisp Hyperspec documentation is in [FORMAT Printer Operations](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cd.htm).

```
* (format t "~a" ''(a #\a))
'(A a)
NIL

* (format t "~s" ''(a #\a))
'(A #\a)
NIL
```